# Prestashop Quick Address Links to external URL

Tags: php, hyperlink, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a small problem on the prestashop on adding custom url into the `quick address`.

The current status of prestashop is `1.7.4.2` fresh install.

[image]

As stated from the image above, I would like to redirect it to external URL `http://www.google.com`, after done creating it is shown in the quick address menu as shown below:

[image]

But when I clicked it, just redirect to:
`http://localhost:8080/prestashop_1.7.4.2/admin067c8ousl/index.php/http://www.google.com`

**Note I have deleted the token as it provided the same result**

**In other words the token is self generated and differs everytime**

I have saw original documentation for that specific issue in [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Quick+Access+Configuration).

When you see on the very bottom, it shows the exact issue I am facing:

> Note that you can create links to other websites, for instance your PayPal account or your webmail. Simply paste the complete URL in the "URL" field, including the http:// prefix.

As I have written correct url, but it still thinks it is a controller.

I have no modified any code yet, is there a way to fix it.

Thank You and Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was for v1.6, v1.7 doesn't allow external urls by default. I submitted an improvement for this, hope they approve the merge. Meanwhile, if you want to use them you can modify the `classes/QuickAccess.php` or add to the override (better option) and change the function `getQuickAccessesWithToken` to the following:

```
public static function getQuickAccessesWithToken($idLang, $idEmployee)
{
    $quickAccess = self::getQuickAccesses($idLang);

    if (empty($quickAccess)) {
        return false;
    }

    $baselink = Context::getContext()->link->getBaseLink();
    foreach ($quickAccess as $index => $quick) {
        if(strpos($quickAccess[$index]['link'], 'http') !== 0 or strpos($quickAccess[$index]['link'], $baselink) === 0){
            if ('../' === $quick['link'] && Shop::getContext() == Shop::CONTEXT_SHOP) {
                $url = Context::getContext()->shop->getBaseURL();
                if (!$url) {
                    unset($quickAccess[$index]);
                    continue;
                }
                $quickAccess[$index]['link'] = $url;
            } else{
                // first, clean url to have a real quickLink
                $quick['link'] = Context::getContext()->link->getQuickLink($quick['link']);
                $tokenString = $idEmployee;

                preg_match('/controller=(.+)(&.+)?$/', $quick['link'], $admin_tab);
                if (isset($admin_tab[1])) {
                    if (strpos($admin_tab[1], '&')) {
                        $admin_tab[1] = substr($admin_tab[1], 0, strpos($admin_tab[1], '&'));
                    }
                    $quick_access[$index]['target'] = $admin_tab[1];

                    $tokenString = $admin_tab[1].(int)Tab::getIdFromClassName($admin_tab[1]).$idEmployee;
                }
                $quickAccess[$index]['link'] = $baselink.basename(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_).'/'.$quick['link'];
                if (false === strpos($quickAccess[$index]['link'], 'token')) {
                    $separator = strpos($quickAccess[$index]['link'], '?') ? '&' : '?';
                    $quickAccess[$index]['link'] .= $separator.'token='.Tools::getAdminToken($tokenString);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return $quickAccess;
}
```

Comment: yes at last, idk why they changed it, and didn't update the document for it. I am able to access external url now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Override is not a clean solution.

You can use free module to adding jquery to your "admin header hook" and do it by jquery to change URL of new created quickAccess